# Cannot convert the expression's type '(@!value UIImage?) -> $T3' to type 'UIImage?'

Tags: swift, uiimage

This code:

```
var uiiv = UIImageView()
let nsurl = NSURL(string: "http://...")
var err: NSError?
let nsd: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsurl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
var img = UIImage(data: nsd)
uiiv.image(img)
```

Produces this error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '(@!value UIImage?) -> $T3' to type 'UIImage?'
```

Can anybody explain to me how to fix this error, and also what the error actually means, it would be helpful to me in the future to understand what things like `$T3` and `@!value` means.

Comment: fixed the problem, many thanks guys. first one to explain `$T3` and `@!value` gets the points.

Comment: You might want to correct `@!value` to `@lvalue`. `@lvalue` means assignable variables (i.e. `var`).

Comment: are you suggesting i correct the error message?

Comment: how can I alter an error message, and what benefit would this give me?

Comment: Is that really `@!value`? In my environment(Xcode6.1), that is `@lvalue`. not `!`, but `l`.

Comment: honestly, the error message I got said `@!value`, not `@lvalue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSData` initializer you are using expects a non optional `NSURL`, but this initializer `NSURL(string: "http://...")` returns an optional. You can either use optional binding or forced unwrapping - in the latter case:

```
let nsurl = NSURL(string: "http://...")!
```

or

```
let nsd: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsurl!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
```

Moreover, the `NSData` initializer returns an optional itself, and I see you've used forced unwrapping - in this case I would use optional binding, because `nsd` can be nil:

```
var uiiv = UIImageView()
let nsurl = NSURL(string: "http://...")!

var err: NSError?
let nsd = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsurl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)

if let nsd = nsd {
    var img = UIImage(data: nsd)
    uiiv.image = img
}
```

---

As for the error message:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(@!value UIImage?) -> $T3' to type 'UIImage?'

that's because you are using a property as if it were a method.

`image` is of `UIImage?` type, but you are using it as a function taking an `UIImage?` and returning an unspecified type `T3`.

By fixing the code properly, the error of course disappears:

```
uiiv.image = img
```

Comment: Xcode insists on putting a `!` at the end of NSData even when I follow your advice

Comment: just remove it manually - also be sure to remove the type when declaring the `nsd` variable, and let type inference do its job: `let nsd = ...`

Comment: ok, cool - so can you also explain what `$T3` and `@!value` mean?

Comment: It's one of the obscure and unmeaningful error messages thrown by the swift compiler - there's a long list of non-sense error messages. I don't have an explanation, but usually in those cases the solution is simple, and in many cases involving optionals

Comment: Actually in this case it gives some hints, and it's not one of the obscure ones I mentioned in my previous comment. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

`image` in `UIImageView` is a property, not method.

you can just assign to it.

```
uiiv.image = img
```

Instead of `uiiv.image(img)`